# Update or Push Embedded Document to Array

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I have two document

```
class Holder
  include Mongoid::Document

  embeds_many :things
end

class Thing
  include Mongoid::Document

  embedded_in :holder
end
```

Is there a way to find if some element exists in Holder.things and updated it or if not create a new one? Similar to the upsert flag in mongoDB.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried so far? Look into the embedded 1-N relationship functions that Mongoid provides ([here](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/relations.html#embeds_many)).

```
@myHolder.things.find_or_create_by(attr: 'val')
# or 
if @myHolder.things.where(attr: 'val').empty? ...
```

Comment: My first try was trying to find it and then always write over it. I was trying to find a better way to do it

Comment: `@thing = @holder.things.where(attr: 'val').first; if @thing.nil? then @holder.things.create(attributes) else @thing.update_attributes(attributes) end`
Sorry for the poor formatting - I guess comments don't support code blocks.